# MDL Tooltip not word-wrapping with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, tooltip, material-design-lite

I'm building a table with data that can potentially be very long, so I've chosen to truncate the text if it's too long and add Material Design Lite tooltips to show the rest of the data when the user hovers over it.

However, when the tooltip is shown, while it does show all of the data, the word-wrapping does not work, so it cuts off long strings. This only happens when I populate text in the tooltips using KnockoutJS. Notice in the screenshot how the right side of the tooltip seems to have less padding; that's because of the problem I've got. That text should be much longer and word-wrapped.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaXfu.png)

```
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
    <div data-bind="text: ServiceTag, attr: { id: 'ServiceTag' + $index() }"></div>
    <div class="mdl-tooltip" data-bind="text: ServiceTag, attr: { for: 'ServiceTag' + $index() }"></div>
</td>

.mdl-tooltip {
-webkit-transform: scale(0);
      transform: scale(0);
-webkit-transform-origin: top center;
      transform-origin: top center;
will-change: transform;
z-index: 999;
background: rgba(97,97,97, 0.9);
border-radius: 2px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
display: inline-block;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 14px;
max-width: 170px;
position: fixed;
top: -500px;
left: -500px;
padding: 8px;
text-align: center; }
```

Comment: What styles are being applied?

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix would be to add manual line breaks <br/>s in your ServiceTag string...not optimal, but it worked for me.

You can also try adding the white-space attribute the the **mdl-tooltip** class (white-space: normal).